# Discord Bot doesn´t respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello everyone I am a new developer and trying to create a first simple bot to test what I could do. In my local tests on my personal computer, everything went absolutely smooth and fine. But when I tried to deploy the bot on my virtual server the bot won't respond to any of my commands.

I work on Ubuntu 16.04 and have a working API Service running.

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const token = "Token (rn stored in the document it self)";
const PREFIX = "quiz!";

const { v1: uuidv1, v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

let mysql = require("mysql"),
    http = require("http");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "quiz",
});
// Build Up Connection
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

function doSQL(sql) {
    connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
        }
    });
}

function IsThereAnythingSQL(sql) {
    connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else if (results.length >= 1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function generateUUID() {
    return uuidv4();
}

client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "join":
            const pollEmbed = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Herzlichen Glückwunsch!**").setDescription("Dein Discord Nutzer ist nun berechtigt die Quiz Applikation zu nutzen!");

            const pollEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Du bist schon Registriert!**").setDescription("Dein Discord Nutzer ist bereits berechtigt die Quiz Applikation zu nutzen!");

            if (IsThereAnythingSQL("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERID = '" + message.author.id + "'") == true) {
                message.channel.send(pollEmbed2);
            } else {
                var USERTOKEN = generateUUID();
                var USERSESSION = generateUUID();

                doSQL("INSERT INTO users (USERNAME, USERID, USERTOKEN, USERSESSION) VALUES ('" + message.author.username + "', '" + message.author.id + "', '" + USERTOKEN + "', '" + USERSESSION + "')");

                message.channel.send(pollEmbed);
            }
            break;

        case "verify":
            let status2 = false;
            let txt;

            let msgArgs2 = args.slice(1).join(" ");

            let sql = "SELECT USERSESSION FROM users WHERE USERTOKEN = '" + msgArgs2 + "' AND USERID = '" + message.author.id + "'";
            connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                else {
                    if (results.length == 1) {
                        status2 = true;
                        txt = results[0].USERSESSION;

                        const pollEmbed4 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor(0xffc300)
                            .setTitle("**Herzlichen Glückwunsch!**")
                            .setDescription("Dein SessionKey lautet: " + txt);

                        if (status2 == true) {
                            message.channel.send(pollEmbed4);
                        }
                    } else {
                        const pollEmbed3 = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Fehler!**").setDescription("Bitte gebe einen Korekten SessionToken ein!");

                        message.channel.send(pollEmbed3);
                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case "id":
            const pollEmbed5 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0xffc300)
                .setTitle("**Das hat funktioniert!**")
                .setDescription("Deine ID lautet: " + message.author.id);

            message.channel.send(pollEmbed5);
    }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I am ready!");
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: try adding the `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES` intents to your client, maybe that fixes the problems you are facing

Comment: Now it says cannot send a empty message whenever i use a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Discord.js V13 they updated how to send embeds

you have to change your code from `message.channel.send(embed);` to `message.channel.send({embeds: [embed1, embed2]});`

read more about that [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc)

I made the required changes to your code, and it should work now!

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const token = "Token (rn stored in the document it self)";
const PREFIX = "quiz!";

const { v1: uuidv1, v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

let mysql = require("mysql"),
    http = require("http");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "quiz",
});
// Build Up Connection
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

function doSQL(sql) {
    connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
        }
    });
}

function IsThereAnythingSQL(sql) {
    connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else if (results.length >= 1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function generateUUID() {
    return uuidv4();
}

client.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case "join":
            const pollEmbed = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Herzlichen Glückwunsch!**").setDescription("Dein Discord Nutzer ist nun berechtigt die Quiz Applikation zu nutzen!");

            const pollEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Du bist schon Registriert!**").setDescription("Dein Discord Nutzer ist bereits berechtigt die Quiz Applikation zu nutzen!");

            if (IsThereAnythingSQL("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERID = '" + message.author.id + "'") == true) {
                message.channel.send({embeds: [pollEmbed2]});
            } else {
                var USERTOKEN = generateUUID();
                var USERSESSION = generateUUID();

                doSQL("INSERT INTO users (USERNAME, USERID, USERTOKEN, USERSESSION) VALUES ('" + message.author.username + "', '" + message.author.id + "', '" + USERTOKEN + "', '" + USERSESSION + "')");

                message.channel.send({embeds: [pollEmbed]});
            }
            break;

        case "verify":
            let status2 = false;
            let txt;

            let msgArgs2 = args.slice(1).join(" ");

            let sql = "SELECT USERSESSION FROM users WHERE USERTOKEN = '" + msgArgs2 + "' AND USERID = '" + message.author.id + "'";
            connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                else {
                    if (results.length == 1) {
                        status2 = true;
                        txt = results[0].USERSESSION;

                        const pollEmbed4 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor(0xffc300)
                            .setTitle("**Herzlichen Glückwunsch!**")
                            .setDescription("Dein SessionKey lautet: " + txt);

                        if (status2 == true) {
                            message.channel.send({embeds: [pollEmbed4]});
                        }
                    } else {
                        const pollEmbed3 = new MessageEmbed().setColor(0xffc300).setTitle("**Fehler!**").setDescription("Bitte gebe einen Korekten SessionToken ein!");

                        message.channel.send({embeds: [pollEmbed3]});
                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case "id":
            const pollEmbed5 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0xffc300)
                .setTitle("**Das hat funktioniert!**")
                .setDescription("Deine ID lautet: " + message.author.id);

            message.channel.send({embeds: [pollEmbed5]});
    }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I am ready!");
});

client.login(token);
```